# Is there a way to print the sum result in one line of code in perl?

Tags: string, perl

Rather than summing the result in one line and printing it in another line?
If I have this data

```
my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;
```

Currently, if I want to print the sum result, I need to write the code like this

```
my $tmp = $a+$b;
print "result=$tmp\n";
```

Is there to the same as above by something looking similar to

```
print "result=$a+$b\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes;

```
print "Result = ", $a+$b, "\n";
```

Comment: Thx a lot. That's pretty simple. I should be able to figure it out

Comment: Alternatively `print "Result=${\($a+$b)}\n";`

Comment: Or one character shorter, `print "Result=@{[$a+$b]}\n";`

Comment: Or `my $str = "Result=".($a+$b)."\n";` or `my $str = sprintf "Result=%s\n", $a+$b;` to embed operation result into arbitrary string.

Comment: @flesk : I try to find the document that can tell me what you answered so that I can do it on my own. How can you get that knowledge?

Comment: I favour `printf 'Result = %d', $a + $b`. Building anonymous data and dereferencing it inside a string is a messy work-around.

Comment: @Jessada Thutkawkorapin, `${ EXPR }` in quotes is a scalar dereference just like outside of quotes. ` \ ` creates a reference from a scalar, so `${\EXPR}` create a reference to the scalar returned by `EXPR` and immediately deferences that reference resulting in the original scalar. The parens are just there to fix precedence.

Answer (score 4):

```
print "Result=", $a+$b, "\n";         # Multi-arg print
print "Result=".($a+$b)."\n";         # Concatenation
print "Result=${\( $a+$b )}\n";       # ref-deref trick (scalar context)
print "Result=@{[ $a+$b ]}\n";        # ref-deref trick (list context)
printf "Result=%s\n", $a+$b;          # printf
print sprintf("Result=%s\n", $a+$b);  # sprintf
```